# Is it possible to output an array of integer between 1 to n using q based policy?

Tags: julia

I am using epsilon_greedy_explorer and neural_network_approximator in Julia. I want to make my neural network have n input nodes and n output nodes, where each output node will give a number between 1 to n. This is what I have formulated. But epsilon_greedy_explorer gives integer as output.

```
# Policy for single_agent
# We will use Agent policy (policy + trajectory)
# Policy used by agent will be QBasedPolicy
# QBasedPlicy consists of learner(updates policy) and explorer (chooses action)
STATE_SIZE = 7
ACTION_SIZE = length(actions)
η = 0.01 # Learning rate
η_decay = 0.001
single_agent_policy = Agent(
    policy = QBasedPolicy(
        learner = BasicDQNLearner(
            approximator = NeuralNetworkApproximator(
                model = Chain(
                    Dense(STATE_SIZE, 32, relu),
                    Dense(32, 32, relu),
                    Dense(32, ACTION_SIZE)
                ) |> cpu,
                optimizer = Flux.Optimiser(ADAM(η), InvDecay(η_decay))
            )
        ),
        explorer = EpsilonGreedyExplorer(
            kind=:linear,
            ϵ_stable = 0.1,
            ϵ_init = 1.0,
            warmup_steps = 100,
            decay_steps = 800,
            is_training = true,
            is_break_tie = true,
            step = 1
        )
    ),
    trajectory = CircularArraySARTTrajectory(
        capacity = 64,
        state = Array{Int64, 1} => (STATE_SIZE)
    )
)
```

Comment: There's a [BatchExplorer](https://github.com/JuliaReinforcementLearning/ReinforcementLearning.jl/blob/master/src/ReinforcementLearningCore/src/policies/q_based_policies/explorers/batch_explorer.jl) to apply the inner explorer along the first dimension. But I'm not sure whether you need it here.

Comment: @JunTian Is there any way to output an array of integers using epsilon_greedy_explorer? Even in multiagent epsilon_greedy_explorer will output the Int64 value.

Comment: Could you explain why you need an array of integers? An explorer is designed to apply to a vector of state-action values and select only one action (the index of the selected value).

Comment: My action space is very large, n^n. I want to output n integers w.r.t. n channels where integers will lie in the interval [1,n]. But this model will not work for large n. Hence, I am thinking of a way to output integers in [1,n] for n channels using epsilon_greedy_explorer, which will reduce my action space to {1,...,n}.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether it makes sense to do so or not. But you may need to implement a customized learner for this task. I'm afraid `BasicDQNLearner` will not work here.